# Activating a conda environment in a singularity recipe

Tags: python-2.7, conda, singularity-container

I'm new to singularity and I would like to activate a conda environment (`myenv`) within a singularity recipe in order to install a package into it (`mypkg`). I've read some related posts but the answers did not solve my problem although the questions are very similar ([Activate conda environment on execution of Singularity container in Nextflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56446195/3894837), [How to activate an Anaconda environment in a Singularity recipe](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55168018/3894837), [Building Singularity recipe from Nipype docker image CommandNotFound](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50259231/3894837)). Could you help me to find what I've missed please?

In my case, `myenv` is automatically activated when I execute the container but I don't succeed to activate it during the container building for installing `mypkg`. I don't have any error message but the package is installed in the base env instead of `myenv`.

```
Bootstrap: docker
From: ubuntu:18.04

%files
    myenv.yml

%environment
    export LC_ALL=C
    export LC_NUMERIC=en_GB.UTF-8
    export PATH="/opt/miniconda/bin:$PATH"
    export PATH="/opt/miniconda/envs/$(head -1 myenv.yml | cut -d' ' -f2)/bin:$PATH"

%runscript
    exec "$@"

%post
    # miniconda2: get miniconda2 version 4.5.1
    wget https://repo.continuum.io/miniconda/Miniconda2-4.7.12.1-Linux-x86_64.sh -O miniconda.sh

    #install conda
    bash miniconda.sh -b -p /opt/miniconda
    export PATH="/opt/miniconda/bin:$PATH"

    #install conda env.yml file
    echo ". /opt/miniconda/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" >> $SINGULARITY_ENVIRONMENT
    echo "conda activate $(head -1 myenv.yml | cut -d' ' -f2)" >> $SINGULARITY_ENVIRONMENT
    /opt/miniconda/bin/conda env create -f myenv.yml

    # Activate conda env, clone and install mypkg
    . /opt/miniconda/bin/activate myenv &&
    git clone https://github.com/mypkg.git &&
    cd mypkg&&
    python setup.py install
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `. /opt/miniconda/bin/activate myenv` try using:

```
. /opt/conda/etc/profile.d/conda.sh
conda activate myenv
```

Using the functions directly is better supported.